# Global timeout doesn't work in WebDriverIO

Tags: webdriver-io

I was trying to setup global delay with `waitforTimeout` as per below classes

**wdio.conf.ts**

```
export const config: WebdriverIO.Config = {
    specs: ['./features/**/*.feature'],
    baseUrl: process.env.UI_PROJECT_HOST || 'http://localhost:4001',
    waitforTimeout: 50000,
    maxInstances: 1,
    framework: 'cucumber',
    specFileRetries: 1,
    reporters: [
        'spec',
        ['cucumberjs-json-fix', {
            jsonFolder: '../reports',
            language: 'en',
        }]
    ],
    cucumberOpts: {
..........
```

**wdio.chrome.conf.js**

```
require('ts-node').register({ transpileOnly: true });
require('tsconfig-paths/register');
module.exports = require('./config/wdio.chrome.chromedriver.conf.ts');
```

**wdio.chrome.chromedriver.conf.ts**

```
import { config } from './wdio.conf';
import {join} from 'path';

const CHROME_ARGS = [
    '--disable-background-networking',
    '--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess',
.
.
.
```

With above I expect to have mentioned delay for all the user interactions when I run the script. Is my understanding correct?

However I can't see this when run the script with `wdio run ./wdio.chrome.conf.js`

I tried this too, but no luck `wdio run ./wdio.chrome.conf.js --waitforTimeout=50000`

[Timeout-1](https://webdriver.io/docs/timeouts/)

[Timeout-2](https://webdriver.io/docs/configurationfile/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the property. waitforTimeout is the MAXIMUM time the driver waits before throwing timeout exception if an element is not found. It does not mean that it will wait for the given time with every action. If the element is found immediately, the execution continues.

Comment: Ok, So is there any option for the mentioned requirement? This is basically for testing purposes just to see the flow. In other words if I can see the browser action in slow motion that's what I after

Comment: it depends! if the tests are very few and a one-time activity, you can simply add a pause. If this is a recurring thing that can be used in the future, you may have to build some wrapper functions which can be used in your tests.

Comment: Sounds like even want to apply for one test, the `pause ` has to be placed in each and every action to see the whole flow run in slow motion rather than configuration level. Is that correct?